# What is the difference between these two codes? Loop through a string and count the number of times the letter appears and add it to my hash

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I am trying to loop through a string:

```
statement = "The Game of Throne Rocks!"
```

with the letter as the key for my hash. The value of my key will be the number of times the letter appears in my string.

I found this code through Stack Overflow:

```
statement.each_char do |char|
  next if char == " "
  result[char] = 0 unless statement.include?(char)
  result[char] += 1
end
```

It works, and I am attempting to rewrite it to my understanding. My code below doesn't work:

```
result = {}
statement.each_char do |char|
  if char == ' '
    next
  elsif result.include?(char)
    result[char] += 1
  else
    result[char] = 0
  end
end
```

Please help.

Comment: Should the bottom code sample read `result.include?(char)` as well?

Answer (score 1):

The original code sample unconditionally executes `result[char] += 1`, while yours only does that the second time a letter is seen.

Your code could also be fixed by initializing the hash entry to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Every time a new character is entered you are making its count to zero, instead you should make it One.
This code works for you.

```
statement = "The Game of Throne Rocks!"
result = {}
statement.each_char do |char|
  if char == ' '
    next
  elsif result.include?(char)
    result[char] += 1
  else
    result[char] = 1
  end
end
result =>  {"T"=>2, "h"=>2, "e"=>3, "G"=>1, "a"=>1, "m"=>1, "o"=>3, "f"=>1, "r"=>1, "n"=>1, "R"=>1, "c"=>1, "k"=>1, "s"=>1, "!"=>1}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
▶ statement = "The Game of Throne Rocks!"
#⇒ "The Game of Throne Rocks!"
▶ statement.downcase.delete(' ').split('').group_by(&:itself).map do |k, v|
▷   [k, v.size]
▷ end.to_h
#⇒ {"t"=>2, "h"=>2, "e"=>3, "g"=>1, "a"=>1, "m"=>1, "o"=>3,
#   "f"=>1, "r"=>2, "n"=>1, "c"=>1, "k"=>1, "s"=>1, "!"=>1}
```

Answer (score 0):

A good example to show how you can solve the same problem with different solutions.

Your solution is flawed in that you initialize the counter to 
`0` even though the character occurred once. If you fix this, then it will work as expected:

```
statement.each_char do |char|
  if char == ' '
    next
  elsif result.include?(char)
    result[char] += 1
  else
    result[char] = 1
  end
end
```

You could use `inject` or `each-with_objcet` to improve the code. Like this you don't need to initialize a hash prior to the loop. I prefer `each_with_object` because you do not need to return the accumulating object from the block, as you need to do with `inject`.

```
count = statement.each_char.inject({}) do |hash, char|
  hash[char] = (hash[char] || 0) + 1 if char != ' '
  hash
end


count = statement.each_char.each_with_object({}) do |char, hash|
  hash[char] = (hash[char] || 0) + 1 if char != ' '
end
```

Here we use the possibility to chain methods of http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html because they return en `Enumerator` when no block is given.

The `(hash[char] || 0) + 1` part initializes the counter to `1` on the first occurence and prevents `nil + 1` cases. You can write this in two lines like this:

```
hash[char] = 0 if hash[char].nil?
hash[char] += 1
```

You could "simplify" that part by using a hash that initializes to `0` for keys that are not found.

```
count = statement.each_char.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |char, hash|
  hash[char] += 1 if char != ' '
end
```

And you could also use mudasobwa's solution which is pretty clever by using `itself`. I'd only change it to use `each_char` instead of 
`split('')`:

```
statement.downcase.delete(' ').each_char.group_by(&:itself).map do |k, v|
  [k, v.size]
end.to_h
```